# Denwer increase max execution time for php-cli

Tags: php

If I try to run composer in my CLI for denwer

```
d:\dev\denwer\home\composer>php composer.phar require dts/ebay-sdk-trading
```

I get "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded". I assume that's because denwer uses cgi php instead of CLI.

Is there a way I can switch php to CLI behaviour or remove the time limit? I don't want to change max_execution_time in global php.ihi.

Answer (score 1):

use `php -d` to set options

documentation link

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

example

`php -d max_execution_time=0`